# Regex to sort files into folders alphabetically by surname?

Tags: regex

I 'm trying to find a way to write a regex to sort files into separate folders alphabetically based on surname. The file names all start with a name but written "first name last name" so I need an expression that will match the first letter of the last word before the first deliminator " - ". For example

```
 John M. Allen - job 00 - october.txt
```

Should match the "A" in Allen and all the other last names beginning with "A" so I can use File Renamer to then move them to a folder called "A"

I'm fairly new to regex and dont know how to go about this one. I'm using File Renamer 6.0.1 which is in JS.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment it's the only tool in my box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b[A-Z](?=[a-z]+\s-\s)
```

[See this.](http://www.regexr.com/39ml5)

This may look at bit complex, but it's not if you understand all the pieces (the \b means match a word boundary, just google 'word boundaries regex' to learn more). The ?= is a look-ahead assertion. I've added a word boundary and some more details in order to avoid bad matches, suppose you had A before the 00 - october part, if I didn't use [a-z]+ and instead \w+ then that would match as well which is not what you want.

Comment: That's excellent thanks. To make it easier for me to select them to move, could I add a REPLACE that would put a non-alphanumeric character at the beginning of the filename. ie: "!John M. Allen - job 00 - october.txt"  ?

Comment: I'm getting some false positives with ones that have no number in the middle section, ie: `John Delbert - Artwork - october.txt` I cant see anyway to adapt it to ignore these. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly robust, given that it won't work for two last names or any funky punctuation, but this should should get you started anyway:

```
(\w)\w+(?<=\w) -
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/lK3oC7/1)

The first letter of the last name is in the first capture group; depending on what language you're using you'll need to sort out how to reference it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that lookbehind?  `(?<=\w)` asserts that the last character matched by the `\w+` part was a word character, which is pointless.  In fact, you can't use lookbehind at all because the regex flavor is JavaScript.